# How to generate columns dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have table with certain number of columns.

I want to populate other table with the data of a particular column of **Table1** as columns of **table2** dynamically.

When I say dynamically I mean to say that when ever any data is added to the column of **Table1** the **table2** is populated with as many number of columns.

Comment: Please rework your question since it is not clear what you're actually trying to do. How is it related to ASP.NET?

Comment: Are you saying new data added to Table1 should be added to Table2, or when a new column is added to Table1 the same column should automatically be added to Table2? (A column is metadata, not data, just to help clarify.)

Comment: Let me clarify: Let us say we have 2 tables Table1 and Table2. Table1 has a column say 'Description'. Now user add 3 rows to it say A,B,C.Now I want that I should write a stored procedure which will take these 3 values and add these values to table2 as columns so that Table2 has A,B,C as columns. This should be done dynamically so that when ever user add any data to the description column of Table1 that data is represented as columns in table2.

Comment: Do you actually want to create a table with the values as column names, or do you just want to pivot the data for output ?

Comment: well, what if there are hundreds rows added in `Table1`'s `Description` column?!! I think it is better to find a different way.  [This topic is almost same to your issue!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390982/database-design-issue-when-adding-new-columns-to-table-from-application)

Comment: This is even worse than I originally thought. Any solution that gets you to this goal (meaning this specific implementation rather than solving the actual problem behind it) should come with the implied guarantee that it contains the potential for multiple levels of catastrophe. Please read this blog post, and more importantly grasp the concept behind it and read the comments. http://erinstellato.com/2012/05/varchar-max-index/ You're the guy trying to ride a cow to work. Tell us what your actual goal is or what problem you're trying to solve, instead of telling us how you want to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the schema on the fly really isn't a good idea, for a number of reasons. From what you've described, I think you would be better off using a view for this. A view will give you the dynamic capabilities you're looking for with fewer side effects.

See this article:
[How to create a view in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I will once again repeat the disclaimer that this is a bad idea, many things can go wrong, and I'm certain there is a better solution to whatever underlying problem you're trying to solve. That said, to answer the explicit question anyway, here is an example of how to do this:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1(Description VARCHAR(32));

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2(ID INT);

GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.CatchNewTable1Data
ON dbo.Table1
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

    SELECT @sql += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
        'ALTER TABLE dbo.Table2 ADD '
        + QUOTENAME(d) + ' VARCHAR(255);' -- guessing on destination data type
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT d = LEFT([Description], 128) -- identifier <= 128
        FROM inserted AS i
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (
          SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
           WHERE name = LEFT(i.[Description], 128)
           AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Table2')
        )
    ) AS x;

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

Now, let's try it out! Try a column that already exists, a multi-row insert where one of the columns already exists, a multi-row insert with dupes, etc. I am not posting a value > 255 nor am I dealing with any fancy characters that will cause a problem. Why? Because ultimately I don't want you to use this solution, I want to solve the real problem. But for the googlers I want to show that there is a solution to the stated problem.

```
-- does nothing:
INSERT dbo.Table1 SELECT 'ID';

-- only adds column 'foo':
INSERT dbo.Table1 SELECT 'ID'
UNION ALL SELECT 'foo';

-- adds both of these columns:
INSERT dbo.Table1 SELECT 'bar'
UNION ALL SELECT 'splan foob';

-- only adds one of these:
INSERT dbo.Table1 SELECT 'blat'
UNION ALL SELECT 'blat';

SELECT * FROM dbo.Table2;
```

Results:

```
ID          foo          bar          splan foob   blat
----------- ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------
```

Don't forget to clean up:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.Table1, dbo.Table2;
```